# Any ideas how to solve or perhaps simplify this integral? Wolfram is unable to.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by:

$$f(x,y) = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{\exp(\cos(x \theta+y))-1}{\cos(x \theta+y)\exp(\cos(x \theta+y))}d \theta $$

I was very much hoping to be able to write $f(x,y)$ without the integral there, any chance this is able to be simplified somehow? Wolfram has trouble doing definite integrals with symbolic manipulations.

I don't even need a completely closed form expression, I would be happy to know $f$ is a Bessel function or some such thing.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha can't even solve the simpler integral you get for $x=1$, $y=0$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(exp+(cos+x)+-+1)+%2F+(cos+x+exp+(cos+x))+for+x%3D0..2pi&dataset=, nor the one that results from that by substituting $u=\cos\theta$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=integral+of+(1-exp+(-x)+)+%2F+(x+sqrt+(1-x%5E2))+for+x%3D-1..1. So I think your chances are slim -- that's the sort of integral that Wolfram|Alpha is usually good at, though there are rare exceptions.

Comment: You don't need a function of two variables.  If
$$
F(t) = \int \frac{(\cos t)-1}{\cos t \;e^{\cos t}} dt,
$$
which is presumably not an elementary function, then change variables to see
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{F(2 x \pi + y) - F(y)}{x}
$$

Comment: At least for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, $$f(n,y) = 2\pi\,{}_1F_2\left(\tfrac{1}{2};1,\tfrac{3}{2};\tfrac{1}{4}\right)\approx6.82681\cdots$$ is independent of $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Too long for a comment)*

A slightly more general observation is as follows: If we define

$$A(x,z):=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{z\cos\theta}-1}{z\cos\theta}\,d\theta,$$

then $A(x,z)=\sum_{a,b=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z/2)^{a+b}}{a!b!(a+b+1)}x\operatorname{sinc}((a-b)x)$. From this, we can verify that $A$

$$A(x+\pi,z)=A(\pi,z)+A(x,-z).$$

In particular, using $A(\pi,-z)=\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z/2)^{2n}}{n!^2(2n+1)}=A(\pi,z)$, we obtain $A(n\pi,z)=nA(\pi,z)$ for any integer $n$. This can be used to derive a special value of

$$f(x,y)=\frac{A(2\pi x+y,-1)-A(y,-1)}{x}, $$

such as $f(\frac{n}{2}, 0) = 2A(\pi,1) = f(n,y)$ for any non-zero integers $n$ and for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$.